# After updating my Jekyll site from version 3 to 4, my Ruby folder (saasc-2.4.0) becomes very big! How to prevent accumulating precious build time?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, saas, jamstack

I am updating my Jekyll JAMstack site from Jekyll 3 to 4, and suddenly my Ruby folder becomes extremely big, compared to what it was.

My site used to be around 20-30MB. it suddenly went to over 150MB?

Is this normal, can I not keep it smaller?

I see that the largest chunk is located inside vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/... i.e. the **gems** folder.

By far the largest folder inside the **gems** folder is the **sassc-2.4.0** folder! It is over 120MB in size?

See also https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/189 is there any way to fix this? The bottom post says:

> We avoid rebuilding binary gems altogether by hosting our own gem repo
> with geminabox and gem-compiler, but due to rubygems/rubygems#3174 the
> repo can only host binary gems built for musl (and a single musl
> version at that).

How to do this?

Comment: Are you use jekyll on your terminal or inside a docker container?

Comment: @KargWare On the terminal.